# Rebase branch after removing file from history

Tags: git

I was working on two branches, A and B. While on the master branch I decided to remove some large binary files that were taking up space in the project history. I did so using:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch "Filename"' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

(from [this site](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data)) on the A branch.

However after doing this I went back to working on the B branch which had not had it's history rewritten. This resulted in the following commit tree

```
+----+  +----+                 +----+
| A1 |->| A2 |---------------->| A5 |
+----+  +----+                 +----+
+----+  +----+  +----+  +----+   /
| B1 |->| B2 |->| B3 |->| B4 |--/
+----+  +----+  +----+  +----+
```

Where A1 and A2 are the same commits as B1 and B2 except for the missing binary file. How could I delete the binary file from the B as well and make the commit tree look like this:

```
+----+  +----+                 +----+
| A1 |->| A2 |---------------->| A5 |
+----+  +----+                 +----+
           \   +----+  +----+   /
            \->| B3 |->| B4 |--/
               +----+  +----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first `git checkout B4` and then `git rebase --interactive A2`. Your `$EDITOR` will be fired up with a file listing lots of commits formated as `pick <ABREVIATTED-HASH> <COMMIT-MESSAGE>`. Remove all those files except the last ones, that should be `B3` and `B4`. After that, save that file, close your `$EDITOR` and `git` will apply your selected commits on top of `A2`. If `git` detects conflicts, it will give you your prompt back and ask you to resolve them. Edit the conflicts, `git add` the conflicted files, and `git rebase --continue`. Do this  until you solve all conflicts. After that, you would have `B3` and `B4` applied on top of `A2`. `git checkout A5`, `git merge B4` and you'll end up with your desired tree.

If there are just 2 commits as in your example, it can be easier to just do:

```
$ git checkout A2
$ git cherry-pick B3
$ git cherry-pick B4
$ git checkout A5
$ git merge B4
```

That's what the hole `rebase` song will do. If you have more commits, it would be more time-consuming. You choose :)